# How to get all the "StoreName" with button label "Make My Store" using xpath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get all the store names with button label "Make My Store", and **ignore** the store name which has button label "Your Active Store".

How can I achieve this using xpath. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out here.
Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZrau.png)

Comment: To make your question more clear, please at least share the html you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath should match all elements with text "Make My Store":

`'//*[text() = "Make My Store"]'`

Since you mention they are buttons, you could specify all buttons with text "Make My Store" as follows:

`'//button[contains(text(), "Make My Store")]'`

Oh, I see what you want now. To get the store name text above each button with "Make My Store", this xpath should work:

`'//button[contains(text(), "Make My Store")]/parent//div[@class="StoreName"]'`

You should be able to find the storename by getting the text of the element(s) found by the above xpath. I don't know what coding language you want to use otherwise I could give an example.

Comment: Thank you, your solution gets me only a part of the answer,  I would need to include the store name as well in the xpath.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that you need to include the store name. Are you talking about the div a couple lines above that button element?  What exactly is the output you are looking for?

Comment: @Ravi see my latest edit, I think I know what you are looking for now.

Comment: The xpath I've just provided should work for that.